# Finding the "lost" and "spurious'' solutions to an ODE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the differential equation:
>   $$ {dy \over dx}=x(y-2)^{1 \over 2} .$$

We can solve the equation by separating the variables.

\begin{aligned}
  {dy \over dx}&=x(y-2)^{1 \over 2}\\
  dy&=x\sqrt{y-2}dx\\
  \int (y-2)^{-{1 \over 2}} dy&=\int x dx\\
  2(y-2)^{1 \over 2}&={x^2 \over 2}+C\\
 (y-2)^{1 \over 2}&={x^2 \over 4}+{C \over 2}\\
 y-2&=\left({x^2 \over 4}+{C \over 2}\right)^2\\
 y&=\left({x^2 \over 4}+{C \over 2}\right)^2+2\\
 \end{aligned}

Then, my question is: What are the 'lost' solutions and the 'spurious' solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can see there's potential to lose a solution when dividing by $\sqrt{y - 2}$ to separate variables, as dividing assumes $\sqrt{y - 2} \neq 0$. Indeed, if $\sqrt{y - 2}$ is identically zero, $y(x) = 2$, and substituting shows that this is indeed a solution.

One can check for "spurious" solutions by substituting the expression you produced for $y$ and seeing for which parameter values $C$ the expression really gives a solution.

Comment: For the "spurious" solutions,if $c=-2,x=0$,then,$y=3$.But in $(y-2)^{1 \over 2}={x^2 \over 4}+{C \over 2}$,it is unvalid for $c=-2,x=0$,is that right？

Comment: If we denote $$y_c(x) = \left(\frac{x^2}{4} + D\right)^2 + 2,$$ then the l.h.s. of the differential equation is $$\frac{dy_c}{dx} = x\left(\frac{1}{4} x^2 + D\right)$$ but this r.h.s. is $$x \sqrt{y_c - 2} = x \left\vert \frac{1}{4} x^2 + D \right\vert ,$$ and these only agree when $\frac{1}{4} x^2 + D \geq 0$. If $D \geq 0$ this is true for all $x$, but if $D < 0$ this is only true for $x$ such that $|x| \geq \sqrt{-D}$. So if we only want solutions defined for all $x$, we must discard the solutions with $D < 0$.

Comment: So you are comparing the differential of the solution and the original function.It is really helpful.Thank you .

Comment: It's simpler than that---it's just taking the functions produced and checking which of them really are solutions (on the desired domain). Anyway, you're welcome, and I'm glad you found it helpful!